# i am using django version 3 and when i tried to work on model managers i got this error

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

i am using django version 3 and when i tried to work on model managers i got this error
ModelManager is giving error

models.py

```
class ProductManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return ProductQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

    def features(self):
        return self.get_queryset().featured()

    def get_by_id(self, id):
        qs = self.get_queryset().filter(id=id)
        if qs.count() == 1:
           return qs.first()
        return None
```

views.py

```
class ProductDetailView(DetailView):

    template_name = "Products/details.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        print(context)
        return context

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        request = self.request
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        instance = Product.objects.get_by_id
        if instance is None:
            raise Http404('Product does not exist')
        return instance
```

error:

```
AttributeError: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'get_by_id'
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is that Django model object querysets don't have a method named 'get_by_id'. You should just use what's provided with Django. This is likely to be what you want:

```py
Product.objects.get(id=1)
```

Substitute 1 by the id that you want..